# Collapsable/expandable text in Latex

Tags: pdf, ocg

I'm writing a manual for a new piece of software, and I would like to be as clear as possible and include entire derivations for the governing equations. However, I understand that most users don't need that level of detail.

Does Latex have the capability for clickable icons to expand/collapse sections of the document in the PDF? I want the user to be able to click an icon to expand the text to show a new piece of the document (to show the derivation of a governing equation) without having the manual bogged down by all of these derivations.

Something like a "Show more" icon would be good, that when clicked shows the derivation.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I don't know if this is possible, but in case it should not: What about showing the "entire derivations" in an appendix with several sections/subsections which could be (hyper)linked?

Comment: packages [ocg-p](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) or [ocgx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) can be helpful

Comment: This has nothing to do with `expansion` in the sense of TeX

Comment: Whole sections (even spanning multiple pages) can be hidden and enabled by means of the `ocgx2` package, but one cannot collapse the space reserved for the hidden content.