# fold / unfold system of equations in long derivation

Tags: ocg

I am showing a long derivation (simplified example here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &=& 0 \\
&\downarrow& \mbox{using eq.}~\ref{eq0} \\
&=& 1 \\
&\downarrow& \mbox{using eq.}~\ref{eq1} \\
&=& 2 \\
&\downarrow& \mbox{using eq.}~\ref{eq2} \\
&=& 3
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{equation}
0
\label{eq0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have only a **folded representation** showing only the line "0=0" and the final "=3" in the produced PDF.  The desired behaviour would be that there is a button between these 2 final lines that, when hovered or pressed, would **trigger a pop up showing the entire derivation**.

The objective is that the reader can quickly see the start and end without having to see all the details in between at first view.  Of course, I could put the derivation in an appendix but navigation would become difficult (especially considering that the intermediate equations themselves refer to other equations).

This question is very much related to:
[Collapsable/expandable text in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327737/collapsable-expandable-text-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I couldn't find a way to adapt the code with the aligned equations.  The picture below gives an example of the desired behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Ideal would be that the size of the pop up would be adapted to the number of aligned equations that it needs to host.  I'm updating with a picture so you can see what I mean

Comment: Oh, no gap.  It should just pop up on top of the existing eqnarray.  When you click outside (or some other intuitive interface), the pop up would disappear

Comment: Which PDF-Reader do you want to use?

Comment: I guess Acrobat Reader is a must.  But it'd be nice to support as many as possible.  Note that I'm developing everything from Overleaf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on J. Kormylo's example without vertical gap and making use of the

[↗`\tootip****{...}{...}[<x-off>][<y-off>]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186/1053) macro (Evince, A-Reader):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%patch hyperref to make PDF Annotations PDF-Layer-(OCG)-aware
\makeatletter
  \let\Hy@setpdfborderOrig\Hy@setpdfborder
  \def\Hy@setpdfborder{\ocgbase@insert@oc\Hy@setpdfborderOrig}%
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2018/01/15
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]]
%            [<link colour>]{<link text>}
%            [<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%            [<x-offset>,<y-offset>]
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes,linegoal}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\let\cListSet\clist_set:Nn\let\cListItem\clist_item:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}mO{0pt,0pt}%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \cListSet\tpOffsets{#9}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \tipshift=0pt%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    %OCG-based (that is, all non-draggable) boxes should not extend beyond the
    %current column as they may get overlaid by text in the neighbouring column
    \setlength\whatsleft{\linegoal}%
  }{%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
  }%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\dimexpr\twd+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax%
    \setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd-\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp+\cListItem\tpOffsets{2}}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\dimexpr\tipshift+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\centerwithin}[2]{% #1=small symbol, #2=wide symbol
  {\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#2{}}}][c]{{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\tempbox{%
\begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}% almost impassible to pre-measure
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \text{using eq.~\eqref{eq0}} \\
&= 1 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \mbox{using eq.~\eqref{eq1}} \\
&= 2 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \mbox{using eq.}~\eqref{eq2}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{align*}
0 &= 0\\
  &\makebox[0pt][r]{%
     \tooltip****{\fbox{\bfseries +}}{\tempbox}[-0.4em,-4ex]%
   }\\
  & = 3
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
0
\label{eq0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Argument of \tpPdfLink has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.209 \end{align*}

Comment: Get http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/pdfbase.sty and http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2/ocgbase.sty and upload them into your project directory on overleaf.

Comment: The links to referenced equations in the popup don't work

Comment: I mean the part "using eq. ()" doesn't click to the place where the equation is defined

Comment: See updated answer: As usual, `hyperref` must be loaded for this and a bit of patching `hyperref` is required. You may want to use AR as the PDF viewer, because in Evince the hyperlinked `\eqref`'s won't disappear with the tip-box.

Comment: In Acrobat Reader the little red rectangle around the equation number stays even when the popup is hidden...

Comment: Is it a problem of the reader or is it something that can be fixed latex-code side?

Comment: Fixed: `\tempbox` is now defined by a simple `\newcommand`, making the patch below `\usepackage{hyperref}` working again.

Comment: Sorry, answer will be updated in a second.

Comment: Update done, no more link rectangles when tooltip is hidden. (In Evince the hidden links are still mouse sensitive, which is a bug in this reader.)

Comment: It looks like now the equations in the popup are not centred any more compared to the ones in the regular text.  Did you notice?

Comment: Well, the tooltip is independent from the regular text, but aligned with the upper right corner of the [+].

Comment: I'm talking about the whole set of equations that have a tooltip that appear shifted to the left compared to regular text

Comment: This is because of the nested `align`'s (from `\tempbox`). The same with @John 's example. Need to think about this.

Comment: Now it looks better.

Comment: Great!  Final question.  Could you tell me how to shift the position of the tooltip box vertically and horizontally wrt to [+]?  Obviously you can't know in advance how high it will be.  But for each specific box, I know.  So I can shift it down in order to have it more centered with the [+]

Comment: For example, I see that if the popup is very big it may go up outside of the page.  In this case, I would like to be able to manually shift it down

Comment: That was already done in the code. Look for the optional argument at the end of the macro: `\tooltip{<link text>}{<box text>}[<xoff>,<yoff>]`

Comment: If you omit the `****`,  the box can be dragged around with the mouse in A-Reader. But then, you cannot place hyperlinks into the `<box text>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77586/discussion-between-ranlot-and-alexg).

Comment: Wow, great post, you worked a lot. I get "Reference `linegoal.0' on page 1 undefined". Do you know what this could be?

Comment: The `linegoal`package is used in the `\tooltip` implementation to make sure the tooltip pop-up box does not extend beyond the right margin of the text. Here we use `\tooltip` in a somehow non-standard way, inside an `align` environment. Maybe it is not `linegoal`'s intended use. The output looks ok, despite the warning. So perhaps we can just ignore it here.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't sure what to do with the equations (1) through (3), so I just left them as is.  I used `\tempbox` to separate the long derivation from the OCG code, and `\switchbox` to align the derivation to the equation.

Note the use of `flalign` to left justify the derivation.  Since equations expand to fill the entire column, it would be difficult to measure the width needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ocgx}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}% simplify source
\newsavebox{\switchbox}% measure width
\savebox{\switchbox}{\fcolorbox{blue}{red}{\bfseries +}}

\newcommand{\centerwithin}[2]{% #1=small symbol, #2=wide symbol
  {\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#2{}}}][c]{{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}% almost impassible to pre-measure
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{flalign*}
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \text{using eq.~\ref{eq0}} &\\
&= 1 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \mbox{using eq.~\ref{eq1}} &\\
&= 2 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \mbox{using eq.}~\ref{eq2}
\end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{align*}
0 &= 0\\
&\mbox{\hspace*{-\wd\switchbox}\switchocg{ocg1}{\usebox{\switchbox}}\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
  \usebox{\tempbox}%
  \end{ocg}}\\
& = 3
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
0
\label{eq0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a variant which overlaps the text.  Notice that only the text that comes after the OCG is visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ocgx}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}% simplify source
\newsavebox{\switchbox}% measure width
\savebox{\switchbox}{\fcolorbox{blue}{red}{\bfseries +}}

\newcommand{\centerwithin}[2]{% #1=small symbol, #2=wide symbol
  {\mathmakebox[\widthof{\ensuremath{{}#2{}}}][c]{{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\switchbox-0.666ex}%

\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
0 &= 0 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \text{using eq.~\ref{eq0}} \\
&= 1 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \mbox{using eq.~\ref{eq1}} \\
&= 2 \\
&\centerwithin{\downarrow}{=} \mbox{using eq.}~\ref{eq2} \\
&= 3
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}}

\begin{flalign*}
&&0 &= 0 &\\
\rlap{\switchocg{ocg1}{\usebox{\switchbox}}\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
  \smash{\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\usebox{\tempbox}}}%
  \end{ocg}} &&&&\\
&&& = 3
\end{flalign*}

\begin{equation}
0
\label{eq0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
2
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way so that the vertical gap (when the box is hidden) would be just for the 3 lines "0=0 \n + \n =3"?  I don't care that the pop up would be completely on top (without transparency) even if it goes over surrounding text after it is revealed.  The reason is that the derivations may be much longer (not more than 1 page) but such a large empty vertical gap would look weird...

Comment: `oxgx` has some issues (e. g, not working with other engines than `pdflatex`, such as `lualatex`). Use `ocgx2` instead.

Comment: One can \smash it, but the result overlays the old text.  One would need to make the OCG background opaque (if possible).  Personally, I put all my derivations into apendixes (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/acoustic/enclosure.pdf for example).