# Aligning formula with \bigvee and \bigwedge

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

This is my LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2} &\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}~p(i,j,n)=\\
=\left(\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,n)\right) &\wedge \left(\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,n)\right)=\\
=\left(\bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,2)\right) &\wedge \left( \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,2)\right)=\\
=(p(1,1,1)\vee p(1,2,1))\wedge (p(1,1,2)\vee  p(1,2,2)) &\wedge (p(2,1,1)\vee p(2,2,1))\wedge (p(2,1,2)\vee p(2,2,2))
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

Now it looks like:

[image]

---

I want to make it look like:
[image]

---

To show what exactly I mean, I made a red line below to show exact alignment that is needed:

[image]

---

How to do that?

Comment: You could use the \centerwithin comand from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431853/fold-unfold-system-of-equations-in-long-derivation/431879?s=1|14.6221#431879

Comment: Also, the last line is too wide.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2} &\centerwithin\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}~p(i,j,n)=\\` complite code here: https://pastebin.com/Vsdbb5b9   deformates the formula like this: https://i.imgur.com/POVE5Lo.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This measures the big wedge once and uses `\mathmakebox` subsequently.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\newsavebox{\tempbox}% can probably use box 0-9

\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\savebox{\tempbox}{$\displaystyle \bigwedge_{n=1}^{2}$}% must be outside environment
\begin{align*}
\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2} &\usebox{\tempbox} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}~p(i,j,n)\\
=\left(\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,n)\right) &\mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{\wedge} \left(\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,n)\right)\\
=\left(\bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,2)\right) &\mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{\wedge} \left( \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,2)\right)\\
=(p(1,1,1)\vee p(1,2,1))\wedge (p(1,1,2)\vee  p(1,2,2)) &\mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{\wedge} (p(2,1,1)\vee p(2,2,1))\wedge (p(2,1,2)\vee p(2,2,2))
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps with an `array`?  (I’m not convinced myself, anyway.)

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}



\begin{document}

Text before the equations.
\[
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}c>{\displaystyle}l}
        \bigwedge_{i=1}^{2}\,\null &
            \bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} &
            \null\,\bigvee_{j=1}^{2}~p(i,j,n) = \\
        = \biggl(\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,n)\biggr) &
            \wedge &
            \biggl(\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,n)\biggr) = \\
        = \biggl(\bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(1,j,2)\biggr) &
            \wedge &
            \biggl( \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}\ p(2,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2}p(2,j,2)\biggr) = \\
        = \bigl(p(1,1,1)\vee p(1,2,1)\bigr)\wedge\bigl(p(1,1,2)\vee  p(1,2,2)\bigr) &
            \wedge &
            \bigl(p(2,1,1)\vee p(2,2,1)\bigr)\wedge\bigl(p(2,1,2)\vee p(2,2,2)\bigr)
    \end{array}
\]
Text after the equations.

\end{document}
```

Note that I changed the sizes of many of the parentheses, and that I wouldn’t recommend repeating the “=” sign at the beginning of the lines.  Moreover, the resulting equation doesn’t fit in the allowed text width.

Here’s the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 4):

The final row is much too long to fit inside the text block defined by the `amsart` document class; you'll have to break that expression across lines. Once the need for that line break is established, aligning the other rows in the way you've laid out in your query has little appeal. The upshot: Just use a simple `align*` environment and be done with it.

Note also that the parentheses produced by `\left` and `\right` are too large, typographically speaking. Use `\bigg`-sized parentheses instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart} % automatically loads 'amsmath' package
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*}
&\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2} \bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(i,j,n) \\
&\quad= \biggl(\,\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(1,j,n)\biggr) 
 \wedge\biggl(\,\bigwedge_{n=1}^{2} \bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(2,j,n)\biggr) \\
&\quad= \biggl(\,\bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(1,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(1,j,2)\biggr) 
  \wedge\biggl(\,\bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(2,j,1)\wedge \bigvee_{j=1}^{2} p(2,j,2)\biggr)\\
&\quad= (p(1,1,1)\vee p(1,2,1))\wedge (p(1,1,2)\vee p(1,2,2)) \\
&\qquad\qquad \wedge (p(2,1,1)\vee p(2,2,1))\wedge (p(2,1,2)\vee p(2,2,2))
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```